# VSTS is showing an empty repo

Tags: azure-devops

I am using VSTS to share my project's code, but since a couple of days I am facing this weird issue:

using a web browser I can navigate to the git repo **Project** on VSTS and it is showing my repo is empty!

[image: Project is empty. Add some code!] <-- screen capture

inside the web page where it is showing the repo is empty I copied and pasted the **URL** where it says "**Clone to your computer**"

I am able to clone the repo using the URL above, into a fresh local repo with no issue, and navigate between the different branches and files after a clean clone, but using a web browser it shows the repot is empty!

how to solve it? probably it is a minor issue, but I am a little worried because it says like my repo was erased or it is empty :/

Comment: Perhaps your local repo has stuff, but your remote does not? Either you're unfamiliar with git or there actually is an issue with VSTS...

what is the URL to clone? i can try to see if I am able to get code from cloning

Comment: I am able to get the code from the URL and clone it on my pc

Comment: but I can not see the files or branches for that repo when I use a web browser only

Comment: please either share the URL to clone, or share your clone command and its output in your question

Comment: You’ve not shown the repository drop down picker or the url in the screenshot.  Are you certain that the repo you’re cloning is the same repo you’ve taken a screenshot of?  If so, showing the command line output and a full screenshot that includes the repo name and clone instructions would be helpful.